# calling a function of template parameter in c++11 where template parameter is chrono::system_clock

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

```
     template< class CLOCK >
    std::string print_date_time( typename CLOCK::time_point p_time ){

        std::stringstream ss;

        std::time_t t = CLOCK::to_time_t(p_time);
        ss << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl;

        return ss.str();
    }

int main(){
std::cout << print_date_time( std::chrono::system_clock::now() );

}
```

I do include proper files, let me know where am going wrong.

Comment: you should elaborate your question. How do you call the function, what error(s) you get from the compiler, ...

Comment: How are you calling it? Does it compile?

Comment: Based on a quick guess of what your problem actually is (basically the same as cpp's code), you can fix it either by spelling out the template type, or by changing the signature to `std::string print_date_time( typename std::chrono::time_point<CLOCK> p_time )`. Haven't figured out the details yet - template argument deduction confuses me. Also, why are you flushing a `stringstream`?

Comment: Alternatively, make `TIME_POINT` the template parameter, and then call `TIME_POINT::clock::to_time_t(p_time);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just dumping my answer as a big block of code here, because I'm afraid I don't have a good explanation of template argument deduction.

I think it's to do with `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` being a `typedef` for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>`, but I'm not sure, and I'm hoping someone will come along with a nice explanation. Until then, I'm just dumping 2 workable solutions.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template< class CLOCK >
std::string print_date_time( typename CLOCK::time_point p_time ){

    std::stringstream ss;

    std::time_t t = CLOCK::to_time_t(p_time);
    ss << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl;

    return ss.str();
}

// You can do this
template< class CLOCK >
std::string print_date_time_2( typename std::chrono::time_point<CLOCK> p_time ){

    std::stringstream ss;

    std::time_t t = CLOCK::to_time_t(p_time);
    ss << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl;

    return ss.str();
}


// Or this
template< class TIME_POINT >
std::string print_date_time_3( TIME_POINT p_time ){

    std::stringstream ss;

    std::time_t t = TIME_POINT::clock::to_time_t(p_time);
    ss << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl;

    return ss.str();
}


int main()
{
    std::cout
        << print_date_time
            <std::chrono::system_clock> // You don't want this!!
                                        // But without it you get template
                                        // argument deduction errors.
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now())
        << '\n';


    std::cout
        << print_date_time_2
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now())
        << '\n';

    std::cout
        << print_date_time_3
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now())
        << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks.

Comment: The (short version of the) explanation is that anything to the left of `::` in a parameter is a non-deduced context. Think about it: the compiler would have to go through *all imaginable types* and inspect each of them if it has a nested `time_point` type which matches the type of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with `print_data_time()` function. This following code works:

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

template< class CLOCK >
std::string print_date_time( typename CLOCK::time_point p_time ){

    std::stringstream ss; 

    std::time_t t = CLOCK::to_time_t(p_time);
    ss << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl;

    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    chrono::system_clock::time_point now = chrono::system_clock::now();
    cout << print_date_time<chrono::system_clock>(now)  << endl; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but what I an trying to achieve or wanted to do was print_date_time( now ). I mean why I have to mention the template parameter CLOCK instead of it being updated by the input parameter I am using.

Comment: Why didn't you ask that in your question to begin with?